# Basic Probability of Selecting From a Jar of Balls

Tags: probability

I am having issues solving a problem using the probability approach (do not want to use the combinatorics approach!). Suppose there are four balls in a jar of colors: 1 Red, 1 Blue and 2 Yellow. 2 Balls are to be selected. What is the probability that only one of the two selections will be Yellow?

Should the solution be this: P(1st pick=Yellow)*P(2nd pick=Not Yellow) + P(1st pick=Not Yellow)*P(2nd pick=Yellow) = ((2/4) *(2/3)) + ((2/4)* (2/3)) = 2/3?

However, using combinatorics to verify the answer, I find that it yields: 1/3.

EDIT: Combinatoric approach, using the notation (n choose k) and the fundamental principle of counting: ((2 choose 1)*(2 choose 1))/(4 choose 2) = 2*2 / 12 = 1/3

Where am I going wrong and why? Why don't I have to take into account of the difference between selecting a Yellow in the first pick versus the second pick (because of which, I am doing the addition in the probability approach)? Can any one care to explain?

Comment: Perhaps you could also describe your combinatorics approach.

Comment: Empirically, I have the chance that one ball will be yellow and the other not-yellow as $2/3$.

Comment: This is right.  Since you have a finite probability space, the combinatorics approach should be essentially the same.

Comment: I have edited to show how I used the combinatoric approach. I don't know how to write the (n k) notation vertically. Hoping it makes sense.

Comment: \binom{4}{2} =6

Comment: I'm just very confused...is this a permutation problem or a combination one?

Comment: Combination, the order isn't important in the end.

Comment: Then how come my taking the order into account in the probability approach is still correct?

Comment: And how do I know that the order is not important?

Comment: By saying order isn't important, I mean the question is not asking for the probability you get one yellow on the first draw and a non-yellow on the 2nd draw, for example. You considered the possible ordered outcomes and combined them to arrive at the final outcome, 1 yellow and 1 not yellow. Sketching out a tree of outcomes, which is possible because of the small number of cases, of course considers order. For much larger problems, sketching the tree isn't feasible and algebraic methods are needed, but the tree sketch can help understand intuitively for small problems.

Answer (score 2):

Among the $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ pairs there is $1$ with two yellows and $1$ with no yellows. That leaves $4$ with (exactly) one yellow.

Answer (score 1):

Your combinatoric approach is at fault, not your probability approach.

$$
\text{'4 choose 2'} = 4C_2= \binom{4}{2} =\frac{4!}{2!2!}
$$

Another (equivalent) approach is to draw the tree of possible outcomes, distinguishing the 2 yellows.

There will be outcomes (y1, y2), (y2, y1), (y1, b) ... etc. with 12 possible pairs (terminal nodes of tree). 8 of these contain exactly one yellow.

Answer (score 0):

> Since in the comments you seem slightly confused you might find this helpful:-

Should the solution be this: P(1st pick=Yellow)*P(2nd pick=Not Yellow) + P(1st pick=Not Yellow)*P(2nd pick=Yellow) = ((2/4) (2/3)) + ((2/4) (2/3)) = 2/3?

> Yes, completely correct

Combinatoric approach, using the notation (n choose k) and the fundamental princi
ple of counting: ((2 choose 1)*(2 choose 1))/(4 choose 2) = 2*2 / 12 = 1/3

> Completely correct method but in numbers this is 2*2 / 6 = 2/3

Comment: Thanks! My question now is, in the probability approach I did take the order into account so didn't that turn it into a permutation problem? How come using combination in the combinatoric approach yields the same answer then?

Comment: Yes, the methods **should** give exactly the same answer!

Comment: But permutation and combination are not the same? One takes order into account and other doesn't?

Comment: The key is in your word "approach". You can use whichever approach you wish in some questions.

Comment: When finding a probability you are finding a ratio. the ratio of two combinations will be the same as the ratio of two permutations if the number of permutations in each case is the **same** multiple of the number of combinations.

Comment: Right! Thank you so much, I'll think about what you wrote! :)